# Differentiation of two different equations yields the same result.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiation of $\frac{3-2x}{(1-x)^2}$ and $\frac{x(4-3x)}{(1-x)^2}$ both yield the same result $\frac{2(2-x)}{(1-x)^3}$.

However, the equations are now equivalent. How is this possible? Am I missing something here? I manually solved it first, but just to double check, I solved it using python as well. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: $0$ and $1$ are different functions by they have the same derivative.

Comment: @hedge98 differentiate x+1 and x, their derivatives are equal. How this is possible?

Comment: If you want to verify that two functions have the same derivative, try subtracting them and simplifying. You should be able to show the function is a constant.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz I get that. However, here we have two equations of different order. I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around how they can yield the same result.

Comment: @TheoBendit, if you mean subtract eq 1 from 2, the you are left with an $x^2$ term here

Comment: @hegde98 difference is exactly 3, a constant :')
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283-2x%29%2F%281-x%29%5E2+-+%284x-3x%5E2%29%2F%281-x%29%5E2

Comment: @hegde98 I'd have to see your working, but I think you've made an error. I also got a constant, and lab bhattacharjee's answer shows how you can obtain it.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz I had completely ignored my denominator. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint

Compare the numerators

$$3-2x-x(4-3x)=3(x-1)^2$$

So, the difference of the two functions is constant if $x-1\ne0$

Now if $f(x)=g(x)+c$

$f'(x)=?$

Comment: I had completely ignored my denominator, my bad.